# How to add the string to Key of the dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have multiple set of dictionary. I have to add Key of ID and UD if ID is 1 or 2. I have downloaded from the mysql table and converted to JSON. Now I need some help for processing.

```
{"Rank": "37",ID = "1", UD= 'a'}
{"Rank": "38",ID = "2", UD= 'b'}
{"Rank": "8",ID = "33", UD= 'a'}
```

Expected out

```
{"Rank": "37",ID = "1a", UD= 'a'}
{"Rank": "38",ID = "2b", UD= 'b'}
{"Rank": "8",ID = "33", UD= 'a'}
```

Comment: What exactly have to tried so far?

Comment: Probably best to add the code you use for doing the query as well.

Comment: New to python, Through Apache Nifi I am able to convert from mysql table to JSON and some transformation. Now I want to execute the script for the Python in Nifi tool

Comment: Have you converted to JSON, or do you have a list of dictionaries?

Comment: *"have to add Key of ID"*: In your example `ID` is the **Key** and `"1"` is the **Value**. So you want to append the **Value** from **Key** `UD` to the **Value** of **Key** `ID` by condition. Read [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working code is given below.

```
def parse_data(input_dict):
    for data in input_dict:
        if data['ID'] in ["1", "2"]:
            data['ID'] = data['ID'] + data['UD']

data = [
    {"Rank": "37", "ID": "1", "UD":'a'},
    {"Rank": "38", "ID": "2", "UD": 'b'},
    {"Rank": "8", "ID": "33", "UD": 'a'}
]
parse_data(data)
print data
```